# how can I add h3 on actionlink

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, html.actionlink

My first ActionLink is ok. But how can I add h3 tags ?

```
<a href="/channel/index/44">@a.Title</a>
@Html.ActionLink(@a.Title, "Index", "Channel", new { @a.Id }, null)
```

How can i do actionlink this link?

```
<a href="/Channel/index/44"><h3>@a.Title</h3></a>
 ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can get HTML markup in your link text is to use `@Url.Action`. For example your code will look like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Channel", new { Id = a.Id })"><h3>@a.Title</h3></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use url.action to get the url

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Channel", new { id = 44 })"><h3>@a.Title</h3></a>
```